# Proving a series converges IFF its sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

My question is this:

Let {$x_k$} be a sequence of real numbers. Let $a_k = x_k - x_{k+1}$ for all natural numbers $k$. I want to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k}$ converges IFF $x_k$ converges.

I believe that I have the reverse direction (if $x_k$ converges then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k}$ converges). For this, I (roughly) said that since $x_{k+1}$ is a subsequence of $x_k$ and $x_k$ converges, then $x_{k+1}$ converges as well. I said that the difference of two converging sequences will also converge, therefore $a_k$ converges. Then if $a_k$ converges, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k}$ converges as well. My first question is if this sounds correct.

Meanwhile, I don't understand how to prove the forward direction. I tried looking at the sequence of partial sums of the series, but I found myself making improper assumptions. So I tried to find a counterexample instead, but I couldn't find one of those either. Any hints on this part? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\frac{1}{n}\to0$ but $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n}$ isn't convergent. So $a_n$ is convergent doesn't imply that $\sum a_n$ is convergent. Here, it suffices to notice that
$$
\forall N\ge0, \sum_{k=0}^N x_{k}-x_{k+1}=x_0-x_{N+1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! So, my proof of the forward direction fails there. That makes me think that it's possible that the forward direction is false then...